# How can I wipe restore points without waiting for the disk cleanup utility to have scanned my whole drive?

Tags: windows

When I would like to remove old restore points on my machine, it takes approx. 5 minutes for the disk cleanup utility to scan the drive and tell me that I can save N megabytes with such operation. I only want to access the system restore point removal utility, is there a way of bypassing this scan and get quickly what I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Start, right-click (My) Computer and click Properties
2. Click System protection link in the left pane
3. In the System Protection options, select a drive-letter and click Configure
4. Click Delete, and click Continue when prompted.
5. Click OK, OK

Comment: :) glad I could help